# Why didn't Light Yagami tell Teru mikami that he can kill people using just the paper?

Tags: death-note

What I'm trying to say is should Light tell Teru that killing from scrape paper is possible, then if Teru kept a real deathnote paper with him 24/7, surely that in the final showdown, whoever names written on that piece of paper they surely will die, won't they?

That way you don't even need to worry about the book switching scheme.

Comment: He **did** tell him. Teru Mikami (X-Kira) did lock away his death note, sending pages to Kiyomi Takada so she can do the killing. They even work closely together to trick the SPK into beliving that X is doing the killing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole point of Teru was to be a decoy. If SPK had seen Mikami using a seperate paper of the real death note would be a give away. For example. Instead of visiting the bank to retrieve the real Deathnote, Megami might have used the paper. Which would still give him away.

Light made sure the Mikami had NO access to the real DeathNote and explicitly said him to only take it out on the D-Day.

This is basically an speculative question containing the What-if Scenarios. You can plausibly say that something might've worked out, but as I have just said above... Chances are it would have blown up more easily. Because SPK would have been dead if Mikami had trusted Light and not gone to retrieve the Real DeathNote from the bank.

EDIT: I get the question was why didn't Mikami keep a seperate real piece of DN paper for the day of the final D-Day instead of the DN. I answered this What-if scenario with a plausible explaination that Mikami may have used it to kill Takada. Then I went on to explain this was why Light didn't want ANY piece of real Death Note with Mikami, to keep the plan full proof.

**Tl;dr Mikami didn't keep the DN paper because Light told him not to. This was because Light just like Near wanted to play complete and full proof game but lost to the external factors of Mello and Mikami**

Comment: You're kinda answering a little bit different kind of question, but I get what you're trying to say. In my what-if scenarios, base of your answer I can see that Mikami used the paper to kill outside the D-day then Near would either assumed the deathnote in the bank is fake or Mikami had paper or such(though I'm not really sure though that if Near know that killing is possible with just the paper, but I assumed he at least think that there's something that mikami could use to kill), at that point there's highly chance that Near will either change the method of meeting or just cancel the meeting

Comment: @Wendy added an Edit to explain. Light explicitly told Mikami to cut off ties with the real DN to make his plan complete. The situtation I created was just to highlight what may have been the reason for this. The answer to the question is, because Light told him not to.

Comment: Also, It is assumed Near knew everything L/Mello knew. Mello had discovered how to kill using pieces of DN. So Yeah.. Near knew.

Answer (score 0):

This is the email x-kira should be recieved prior to Jan 28th...

In exactly 1 month and 29 days from today, the 26th of January. Do not go to the bank to pick up the note. Instead and I suggest sometime in December. Make 2 copies not one of the notebook. Keep one in your brief case and the other in the bank vault. Keep the original but burry it by using a name to do so for you. That way you cannot be tracked. Then keep a page on you and on the day of 28th January at 1pm. Use this page to rest on the fake that the spk will use. Write down Nate River first. Then kill the rest except light Yagami.

-LY ;]

Comment: Hi. While some people might understand your answer, please explain it, still, and do not just cite something and leave it at that. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies, if light and teru had planned this accordingly then Kiras legacy would remain in tact. Even if Mikami still went to the bank that day, by making two copies instead of just one would mean the SPK picks up the fake thinking they have swapped the fake for their own, basically a fake for a fake while the real one remains hidden. Also by using another victim to burry the note book means you only need to bring one page with you on the day of the spk meeting. What you end up doing is making three fakes, and this third one is for that.

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question that was asked.